# An error occured while parsing an XML document

Tags: xml, coldfusion, xml-parsing, coldfusion-9

I am getting this error while service call which returns XML response.
I am unable to find out and this Issue is recurring for some time.

**Error:**

```
An error occured while Parsing an XML document.
The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>"
```

---

**(Update from comments)**

I am getting XML from [IP Address Geolocation XML API](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php). Below is the XML response. It's correct by most times I get that error.

**XML response:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <statusCode>OK</statusCode>
  <statusMessage>
  </statusMessage>
  <ipAddress>x.x.x.x</ipAddress>
  <countryCode>US</countryCode>
  <countryName>UNITED STATES</countryName>
  <regionName>NEW YORK</regionName>
  <cityName>NEW YORK CITY</cityName>
  <zipCode>10112</zipCode>
  <latitude>40.7143</latitude>
  <longitude>-72.006</longitude>
  <timeZone>-03:00</timeZone>
</Response>
```

Comment: Sound like invalid xml being returned, we'll need to see the content of what is returned to evaluate further

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, are you trying to get ColdFusion to return XML and you are in debug mode?

Comment: I added the XML response from the comment to the question.  Note that there is no `hr` element in the response.  This disconnect brings me back to the HTML error/context page possibility I mention in my answer below.

Comment: *It's correct by most times I get that error.* It sounds like what you posted is not the actual response received when the error occurred. You need to add some debugging. Add a try/catch and log the complete response when the error occurs. As @kjhughes suggested, it certainly sounds like you are getting back HTML - not the well formed XML above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are probably issues with the request being given to the service or with the service itself, and the service is returning, not a nice XML message as expected, but instead a **HTML error page** which includes an unterminated horizontal rule (`hr`) element.  Examine the HTML for clues as to what you might need to do differently with your request.  Be sure to consider whether service is expecting you to POST to its endpoint rather than GET.  Check the media type of your Accept header.  Also check authentication.  Finally, make sure you're not re-using a buffer improperly such that there's residual HTML before or after the proper XML response from the service.